# How to combine multiple rings on chemfig

Tags: chemfig, mol2chemfig

I am trying to create the following structure on `chemfig`, but some things are not aligning or going to the correct places. Please help.

[image]

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\chemfig{Mo*3(-*3(--)-*3(--)-)*3(---)}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd just draw the edges manually instead of using `*3` loops, using `\phantom` if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I'm going to use is the same as the user **polyn**, with a little more explanation (result of a weekend with little to do)

First, we build the central triangle of molybdenum (Mo), all properly marked (a, b, c) and adjust the position of the triangle [:-30]

```
\chemfig{[:-30]Mo?[a]*3(-Mo?[b]-Mo?[c]-)}
```

[image]

Then we add the outer triangles of selenium (Se), red, blue and green.

```
\chemfig{[:-30]Mo?[a]*3(-Mo?[b]*3(-Se?[c])-Mo?[c]*3(-Se?[a])-)*3(-Se?[b])}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{atom sep=6em}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\chemfig{
    [:-30]Mo?[a]*3(-Mo?[b]*3(-Se?[c])-Mo?[c]*3(-Se?[a])-)*3(-Se?[b])
    }
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]